# Finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Grove's book Algebra, Proposition 3.7 at page 94 is the following

> If $G$ is a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group $F^*$ of a field $F$,
>   then $G$ is cyclic.

He starts the proof by saying "Since $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups ...". But this is only true if the Sylow subgroups of $G$ are all normal. How do we know this?

Comment: Multiplication is commutative. So $G$ is abelian and every subgroup is normal.

Comment: For a finite group, $G$ is nilpotent if and only if it is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: A slight generalization of the lemma/theorem you are wondering about is topic of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59665/any-periodic-abelian-group-is-the-direct-sum-of-its-maximal-p-subgroups) (in the moment there is no answer, but a good comment by Geoff).

Comment: See also : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/

Comment: See also Stroppel, Locally compact groups, Theorem 6.32 and corollary 6.33.

Comment: See also: [sheet 3](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/teaching/15Aut/M3P11/exsht3.pdf) and [solutions](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/teaching/15Aut/M3P11/solns3.pdf) Exercise 3

Answer (score 149):

There's a simple proof which doesn't use Sylow's theory.

**Lemma.** *Let $G$ a finite group with $n$ elements. If for every $d \mid n$,  $\# \{x \in G \mid x^d = 1 \} \leq d$, then $G$ is cyclic.*

If $G$ is a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field, then $G$ satisfies the hypothesis because the polynomial $x^d - 1$ has $d$ roots at most.

*Proof.*  Fix $d \mid n$ and consider the set $G_d$ made up of elements of $G$ with order $d$. Suppose that $G_d \neq \varnothing$, so there exists $y \in G_d$; it is clear that $\langle y \rangle \subseteq \{ x \in G \mid x^d = 1 \}$. But the subgroup $\langle y \rangle$ has cardinality $d$, so from the hypothesis we have that $\langle y \rangle = \{ x \in G \mid x^d = 1 \}$. Therefore $G_d$ is the set of generators of the cyclic group $\langle y \rangle$ of order $d$, so $\# G_d  = \phi(d)$.

We have proved that $G_d$ is empty or has cardinality $\phi(d)$, for every $d \mid n$. So we have:

$$\begin{align}
n &= \# G\\
& = \sum_{d \mid n} \# G_d \\
&\leq \sum_{d \mid n} \phi(d) \\
&= n.
\end{align}$$

Therefore $\# G_d = \phi(d)$ for every $d \vert n$. In particular $G_n \neq \varnothing$. This proves that $G$ is cyclic. QED

Comment: Very nice proof. It may be noted that the last equality $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$ is derived from the very same argument applied when $G$ _is_ the cyclic group of order$~n$, using the additional knowledge that in this case elements of every order $d|n$ do exist. In other words no knowledge at all about the values $\phi(d)$, apart from the fact that the are well defined, is used.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, what are the $\phi(n)$?

Comment: @JuanPablo: That's [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), the number of non-negative integers${}<n$ that are relatively prime to$~n$.

Comment: @Andrea or whoever can answer, can you explain what the # notation means, please?

Comment: @ALannister It simply means the cardinality of the following finite set (the # notation is typically only used when talking about finite sets, so "cardinality" here means "number of elements").

Comment: How do we get the inequality less than or equal to after “so we have”? @andrea

Comment: @abeliangrape - That is obvious. Either $\#G_d=0$ or $\#G_d=\phi(d)$; in either case, $\#G_d\leq\phi(d)$.

Comment: Why does $\langle y\rangle$ have cardinality $d$?

Comment: @Koro by easy consequences of the definition of order, since $y$ has order $d$, $1, y, y^2, ..., y^{d-1}$ are all distinct elements in $G$, and they are the elements of the group generated by $y$, $\langle y\rangle$

Comment: @Fra: Yes. I had misunderstood the definition of $G_d$. Since y is in $G_d$, it is of order $d$, hence the cardinality of $\langle y\rangle$ is $d$. Thanks.

Answer (score 71):

We know that if $G$ is a finite abelian group, $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product $\mathbb{Z}_{(p_1)^{n_1}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{(p_2)^{n_2}} \times \cdots \times  \mathbb{Z}_{(p_r)^{n_r}}$ where $p_i$'s are prime not necessarily distinct.

Consider each of the $\mathbb{Z}_{(p_i)^{n_i}}$ as a cyclic group of order $p_i^{n_i}$ in multiplicative notation. Let $m$ be the $lcm$ of all the $p_i^{n_i}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,r.$ Clearly $m\leq {p_1}^{n_1}{p_2}^{n_2}\cdots{p_r}^{n_r}.$ If $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p_i)^{n_i}}$ then $(a_i)^{({p_i}^{n_i})}=1$ and hence $a_i^m=1.$ Therefore for all $\alpha \in G,$ we have $\alpha^m=1;$ that is, every element of $G$ is a root of $x^m=1.$

However, $G$ has ${p_1}^{n_1}{p_2}^{n_2}\cdots{p_r}^{n_r}$ elements, while the polynomial $x^m-1$ can have at most $m$ roots in $F.$ So, we deduce that $m={p_1}^{n_1}{p_2}^{n_2}\cdots{p_r}^{n_r}.$ Therefore $p_i$'s are distinct primes, and the group $G$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_m.$

Comment: In the second paragraph third sentence: It is not true that if $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p_i)^{n_i}}$, then $(a_i)^{({p_i}^{n_i})}=1$. Take $2 \in \mathbb{Z}_{3^2}=\mathbb{Z}_9$. We have $2^9 =512 \equiv 8 \pmod 9$.

Comment: @AlJebr I don't know if I understand this correctly, but $2^9$ should be supposed to mean $2+2+2+\dots+2$ for 9 times ? So the result is clearly divisible by 9.

Comment: As, @user5826 pointed out , there is a glitch in the proof . But that can be rectified . Observe that , order of every element in G , devides m , so they are roots of the equation $ x^m-1$ Now how many roots can , $x^m-1$ , can have ?  Because F is a field , it will have exactly m roots and number of distinct roots $ \le m$ . Number of elements in G is , $p_{1}^{a_{1}}...p_{k}^{a_{k}}$ . So , $p_{1}^{a_{1}}....p_{k}^{a_{k}})\le m$ . We previously saw the reverse inequality, thus , $p_{1}^{a_{1}}...p_{k}^{a_{k}}= m$ . m being l.c.m ,  no two $p_{i}$'s can be equal . So , gcd of any pair is 1.

Comment: Excuse , the glitches above ( the 5-min editing time frame passed before noticing much !!!) .

Answer (score 28):

Note that this result is not true if $F$ is a skew field (division ring), as is illustrated by the quaternion group $Q_8$ inside the quaternions. So one must use commutativity somewhere, and this usually happens implicitly by using that the polynomial $X^d-1$ can have at most $d$ roots in $F$; this is for instance the case in the answer by Andrea, where the proof of the lemma does not use commutativity. Here is a somewhat different approach that exploits commutativity a second time.

**Lemma.** *The set of orders of elements in a finite Abelian group is closed under taking least common multiples.*

(Edit: This happens to be the subject of [another math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10616/18880). It may seem quite hard, unless one realises that [in Abelian torsion groups, different prime factors can be considered independently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1564925/18880) due to a canonical direct sum decomposition, after which the question becomes trivial. Here I'll leave my original proof below, which follows [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10618/18880) to that question.)

*Proof.* The set of orders (in any group) is certainly closed under taking divisors: if $x$ has order $n$ and $d\mid n$ then $x^{n/d}$ has order $d$. Now if $a,b$ are orders of elements in an Abelian group and $\def\lcm{\operatorname{lcm}}m=\lcm(a,b)$, then there are relatively prime $a',b'$ with $a'\mid a$, $b'\mid b$, and $a'b'=m$: it suffices to retain in $a'$ those and only those prime factors of $a$ whose multiplicity in $a$ is at least as great as in $b$, and to retain in $b'$ all other prime factors of $b$ (those whose multiplicity exceeds those in $a$). Now if $x$ has order $a'$ and $y$ has order $b'$, then these orders are relatively prime, whence $\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle=\{e\}$, and their product is$~m$ so that
$$
 x^iy^i =e\iff x^i=e=y^i\iff (\lcm(a',b')=a'b'=)\; m\mid i,
$$
and therefore $xy$ has order $m$. QED

Now to prove the proposition, let $n=\#G$, and let $m$ be the least common multiple of all the orders of elements of $G$. By Lagrange's theorem the order of every element divides$~n$, whence $m\mid n$ by the property of least common multiples. But one also has $n\leq m$ since all $n$ elements of $G$ are roots of the polynomial $X^m-1$ in the field$~F$. Therefore $n=m$, and by the lemma (using that $G$ is commutative since $F$ is so) $G$ has an element $g$ of order $m=n=\#G$, so that $G=\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic.

Comment: For another proof done the same way see [this May 2011 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38266/242).  Note that Marc had earlier critiqued this method  of proof in [this Sep 2012 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/191992/242) so it's a bit puzzling to see him repeat it years later.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a number-theoretic proof .

Let $o(G) = n$ .
Then , $d|n$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^{d}-1|x^{n}-1$ . 
Or, $x^{n}-1=g(x).(x^{d}-1)$ , where , $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree , $n-d$ . 
Now, if $x^{d}-1$ has less than d distinct roots , F being a field,$g(x)$ can't have more than $n-d$ roots resulting less than $n$ distinct roots for $x^{n}-1$ , which is absurd as $o(G)=n$ .

Thus , $G'=(\alpha\in G : \alpha^{d}=1)$ , is a subgroup of $G$ .
Let, $\psi(d)$ be the number of elements of order d in $G'$ , then , $\sum_{c|d} \psi(d)= d$ .

By , Möbius Inversion formula ,
$\psi(d)=\sum_{c|d}\mu(c).\frac{d}{c}$.....(1) , where $\mu$ is Möbius function.

We know , $\sum_{c|d}\phi(c)=d$ . Applying , Möbius Inversion formula
to it we observe , $\sum_{c|d}\mu(c).\frac{d}{c}$....(2).

Using (1) and (2) , we may conclude, $\psi(d)=\phi(d)\geq1$ .

Putting , n in place of d , the theorem is proven.

Answer (score 0):

This is another elementary proof that uses only the fact that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots in a field.

So, let $F$ be a finite field let $g$ be an element of maximal possible order $n$ in the multiplicative group $F^*=F\setminus\{0\}$ of $F$. Let $H:=\{g^k:0\le k<n\}$ be the cyclic subgroup of $F^*$, generated by the element $g$. If $H=F^*$, then the group $F^*$ is cyclic and we are done. So, assume that $H\ne F^*$. Observe that every element $x\in H$ satisfies the equation $x^n-1=0$, which has at most $n$ roots in the field $F$. Therefore, $H=\{x\in F:x^n=1\}$. Let $p$ be the smallest positive number for which there exists an element $y\in F^*\setminus H$ such that $y^p\in H$. The minimality of $p$ implies that $p$ is a prime number. Let $k\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ be the smallest possible number such that $y^p=g^k$ for some element $y\in F^*\setminus H$.
We claim that $k<p$. Assuming that $k\ge p$, we can observe that the element $z=yg^{-1}\in F^*\setminus H$ has $z^p=(yg^{-1})^p=g^{k-p}$, which contradicts the minimality of $k$. If $k=0$, then $y^p=g^k=1$ and $y\notin H$ imply that $p$ does not divide $n$. In this case the element $yg\in F^*$ has order $pn>n$, which contradicts the maximality of $n$. This contradiction shows that $k>0$. It follows from $0<k<p$ that the element $g^k$ has order $d>\frac{n}{p}$. Then the element $y$ has order $pd>n$, which contradicts the maximality of $n$. This is a final contradiction showing that the group $F^*=H$ is cyclic.

Answer (score -2):

Let $G$ be a finite group with $n$ elements of a field with the field's multiplication operation. Let $d \: | \: n$ and consider the set $G_d$ containing elements of $G$ with order $d$. Suppose $G_d \neq \varnothing$, so there is $y \in G_d$.

Let's generate a cyclic group $\langle y \rangle$. From group theory, generators of $\langle y \rangle$ are elements of $\langle y \rangle$ that are relatively prime to $|\langle y \rangle| = d$. And because any other elements having orders different than $d$ could not generate $\langle y \rangle$, $G_d$ contains all elements that generate $\langle y \rangle$, so $\#G_d$ = $\phi(d)$.

(*$\#G_d$ is number of elements of $G_d$; $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.*)

Let's partition $G$ into sets of elements with the same order. For example if $G = Z_{10}$, then it would be partitioned into sets of elements: $\{0\}$, $\{5\}$, $\{2, 4, 6, 8\}$ and $\{1, 3, 7, 9\}$ of order $1$, $2$, $5$, and $10$ respectively. By Lagrange's theorem, all elements of a group must have their orders divide the order of the group, so by partitioning G into all $d \: | \: n$, we would have the whole $G$, and having a formula as following:

$$n = |G| = \sum_{d|n} \#G_d = \sum_{d|n} \phi(d)$$

Borrowing Gauss' divisor sum we also have the following formula:

$$\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n$$

To recapitulate, we have shown that $\#G_d = 0$ or $\#G_d = \phi(d)$, but if $\#G_d$ could be equal to $0$, then we would have:

$$n = |G| = \sum_{d|n} \#G_d \leq \sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n$$

which is false because we would have $|G|$ less than $n$. So $\#G_d = \phi(d)$, could not be $0$, and in particular for $d = n$ and $y_n \in G_n \neq \varnothing$, we are guaranteed to have $y_n$, so is $\langle y_n \rangle$ as well.

Then note that $\langle y_n \rangle = \{x \in G \: | \: x^n = 1\}$, and as $|\langle y_n \rangle| = n$, that is all elements of $G$ (*because $G$ is already defined as a finite group with $n$ elements*). This proves that $G \cong \langle y_n \rangle$ hence cyclic.