# A question from Topics in algebra-IN Herstein.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that if a abelian group has elements of order $m$ and $n$ then it has a subgroup of order equals to $lcm[m,n]$.

I am new to group theory so please explain....

Comment: Since G is abelian, you know any prime p, a factor of |G| is the order of N, a subgroup of G. That subgroup is a normal to G by G abelian. Now replace G by G/N. Then proceed to construct this group of order lcm(m,n) in this manner.

Comment: I think this question is not a duplicate of the linked question. True, one can deduce the result here from that answer, but this one can be done with less machinery, and OP mentioned being new to group theory.

Comment: @Andre Surely it would be better to just give an answer to the original question? The questions *are* identical, if you do not include the OPs efforts.

Comment: @user1729: Our definitions of identical are not identical. This question is about *elements* of orders $m$ and $n$. The other is about *subgroups*. One can use the subgroups one to prove the elements one. But a proof of the elements one can be made more concrete.

Comment: @Andre Ah, sorry, I missed the element/subgroup subtlety. However, this question is so standard that it has to be a duplicate, and a quick search reveals the following essentially identical question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/255894/10513 (although I am sure a better example exists).

Comment: I expected that  the question was a duplicate of *something*. That was why I did not write out a construction (product for $m$ and $n$ relatively prime, take appropriate powers first otherwise to "separate" the factorizations). A closure as duplicate should lead OP and others to an answer that is directly relevant.