# Let $G$ be an abelian group;$H$, $K$ are finite cyclic subgroups. Show that $G$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $lcm(r, s)$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $H$ and $K$ be finite cyclic subgroups with $|H| = r$ and $|K| = s$. Show that $G$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $lcm(r, s)$.

I have seen [Let G be abelian, H and K subgroups of orders n, m. Then G has subgroup of order lcm(n,m).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465742/let-g-be-abelian-h-and-k-subgroups-of-orders-n-m-then-g-has-subgrou) However, since it is required to show that $G$ contains a *cyclic* subgroup of order $lcm(r, s)$, I still have no clue.

This is an exercise problem on Fraleigh *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* (p.68, Exercise 56), after the section in which cyclic groups are introduced.

Comment: @lhf Ah sorry. Yes, I meant that!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255894/abelian-group-element-orders, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635906/order-of-element-equal-to-least-common-multiple, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/order-of-elements-in-abelian-groups, and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. If $H$ and $K$ are cyclic and their orders are coprime, then $H\times K$ is cyclic.
2. $\dfrac{lcm(r,s)}r$ is coprime to <del>*r*</del> $\dfrac{lcm(r,s)}{s}$ and is a divisor of $s$.

---

Edit: Thanks to @lhf's comment, (2) is not necessary. We only need to note that if
$$|H|=r=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}\text{ and } |K|=s=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}$$
then $H$ is the product of the corresponding cyclic groups of orders $p_1^{a_1},\dots, p_k^{a_k}$. Same goes for $K$.

On the other hand, $$lcm(r,s)=p_1^{\max(a_1,b_1)}\cdots p_k^{\max(a_k,b_k)}$$ and we can pick out the corresponding components from $H$ or $K$ depending on whether $a_k>b_k$ or not.

Comment: Counterexample to #2: $r=2$, $s=4$.

Comment: #2 still not right... $r=12=2^2\cdot 3$, $s=18=2\cdot 3^2$.

Comment: @lhf I think it's correct. But see edit.