# Group $G$ cyclic as it coincides with the multiplicative group of a finite field

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

I have a group $G=(\mathbb{Z}_{251}^{*}, \cdot)$ with generator $g=71$ (so, having a generator, I'm given with the fact that is cyclic, right?)

further in the example of my study notes I read: "$n = |G| = 250$ ...
$G$ is cyclic as it coincides with the multiplicative group of a finite field"

Could someone give me a justification for this?

Answer (score 2):

$251$ is a prime number, thus $\mathbb{Z}_{251}$ is a field. I believe $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{251}$ are the non zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{251}$.

[Prove that the group, under multiplication, of all nonzero elements in a finite field must be a cyclic group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405921/prove-that-the-group-under-multiplication-of-all-nonzero-elements-in-a-finite)

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z_{251}^*}$ is defined as the set of the equivalence classes modulo $251$ smaller than $n$ and with no common factor with $n$ except for the neutral element $1$

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic theorem in ring theory that any finite subgroup of the group of units of an integral domain is cyclic. I remember the proof to be annoying, but it can be found in lots of places.