# Let $L = \mathbb F_2[X]/\langle X^4 + X + 1 \rangle$ is a field. Show $L^* = L / \{0\} = \langle X \rangle$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $L = \mathbb F_2[X]/\langle X^4 + X + 1 \rangle$ is a field. Show $L^* = L / \{0\} = \langle X \rangle$ is cyclic.

I've proven that $X^4 + X + 1$ is irreducible, so $L$ is a field. I also know that $X^5 + X + 1$ is not irreducible. Also I've proven that $|L| = 16$.

Could someone help me out proving that $L^*$ is cyclic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the group is of order 15 any element must have order 1,3,5 or 15.

in any field the equation $x^k = 1 $ can have at most k roots, so the number of elements with order less than $15$ is at most $1 + 3 + 5 = 9$

hence there must be an element of order 15

i will add, after the query from OP, that a slightly more sophisticated form of this  argument will show that for any finite field its multiplicative group is cyclic.

Comment: Can you explain a little more ? Indeed $x^k = 1$ has at most $k$ roots. But in this case it has $15$ since every element to the power of the group is $1$ ?

Comment: no, i have no desire to start sentences with capital letters except in case the first word is a proper noun, or i am quoting someone verbatim. perhaps you could supply them mentally, since the algorithm required is very simple?

Comment: @user111854 set k=1, one root. set k=3 then at most 3 roots (one of which is the k=1 solution) so in fact at most 2 elements of order 3. set k=5, then, likewise, at most 4 elements of order 5. so there must be at least 8 elements of order 15 as this is the only remaining possibility. (note that 8 is the size of the set of +ve numbers <16 which are relatively prime to 15.)

Comment: there is a useful discussion of the question on mathoverflow (2011) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic

Comment: Thanks David for your enlightning answer.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate $X,X^2,\ldots, X^{15}$ (modulo $X^4+X+1$) and show that you get everything in $L^*$.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about that too, but that is not an elegant approach unless the problem is very small.

Comment: For the purpose of such calculations 15 is a small number!

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative group of a finite field is always cyclic.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic.

Comment: I have the lemma: Let $F$ be a finite field. Then $|F| = p^n$, where $p$ is prime $n \ge 1$ and there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ such that $F \cong \mathbb F_p[X]/\langle f \rangle$. Can I use this ? Let $F = \mathbb F_p$ ?

Comment: That won't help you prove it cyclic. You can either do it directly for this case only, as suggested by Casteels, or you can use the general result that finite subgroups of multiplicative groups of fields are cyclic.