# How to prove that G is a cyclic Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Suppose $G$ is a finite Abelian group and, $\forall\ n\in \mathbb{N} $, there exist at most $n$ elements in $G$ which satisfy $x^n=1$. Prove $G$ is cyclic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure.. can I take $n$ the number of elements and then take an element of $G$ that satisfies the equation and use it as generator of the cyclic group??

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense. Do you mean less than or equal to?

Comment: Hint: What must finite Abelian groups look like?

Comment: I think you mean "less than or equal to n elements", no?  Assuming that, then the argument is essentially the same as in the standard proof that any finite subgroup of a field is cyclic, which you can find, eg, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets prove it by contradiction.

Let $G$ is not cyclic and finite abelian, we can find an element $g\in G$ which has maximal order among elements of $G$, say order $k$ and  $k < |G|$ . Now pick an element $h\in G$ \ $<g>$ and let $|h|=m$ then obviously $m \le k$ as $k$ is maximal among orders of elements of $|G|$.

Now consider $l=\text{lcm} (k,m) $. As $G$ is abelian there exist an element of order $l$ and obviously $l \ge k$, so it implies by maximality of $k$, that $l=k$. But $l=k \implies m|k\ $ that is $k=tm$ for some  positive integer $t$. Now note that all elements $\{1,g,g^2,\dots g^{k-1}\} \cup \{h\}$ satisfies $x^k=1$, thus more than $n$ elements satisfies $x^k=1$.

**Hence Proved**

Comment: NO, order of $gh$ divides $l$, doesn't have to be $l$