# Prove that a finite group of complex numbers are the $n$th roots of unity

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, finite-groups

Prove that if we have a finite group of complex numbers they are the $n$th roots of unity for some finite integer, $n$.

I have seen some clunky ways of doing this but is there a very short simple solution?

Comment: @lulu why did you delete your comment ? I think, it was pretty helpful.

Comment: @Peter  because I realized that the OP's question really was "show that a finite subgroup of a multiplicative group of a field is cyclic", not that every element in such a group was a root of unity.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic) are some proofs...I wouldn't say that any of them were truly short nor simple.

Answer (score 8):

Let $R_{n}$ be the set of $n$-th roots of unity. This has order *at most* $n$, as it is the set of roots of the polynomial $x^{n} - 1$. (I am using as little information as possible. Of course if $\omega_{n} = e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{n}}$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then $R_{n}$ is cyclic of order $n$, generated by $\omega_{n}$.)

If your multiplicative group $G$ of the complex numbers has finite order $n$, then [a consequence of Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications) tells you that for any $a \in G$ we have $a^{n} = 1$.

We have just shown that $G \subseteq R_{n}$. Since $G$ has $n$ elements, and $R_{n}$ has (at most) $n$ elements, they're equal.

Comment: Very nice. And in keeping with the proofs in the comment provided by @lulu, all that this proof uses about the complex numbers are the field axioms.

Comment: @LeeMosher, thanks for the appreciation and the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Any element of this group must have absolute value 1, or its powers would all have different absolute value, which gives an infinite group.

Now let $\phi$ be the element of the group with the smallest positive angle from the real axis (which must exist, as the group is finite). Now $\phi$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, as the group is finite, and we claim that the entire group is the group of $n$th roots of unity. Towards a contradiction, suppose that there is $\psi$ in the group which is not a power of $n$. Then it must lie, on the circle, inbetween $\phi^n$ and $\phi^{n+1}$ for some $n$. But then $\phi^{-n}\psi$ would have a smaller angle with the real axis than $\phi$, which is impossible by definition of $\phi$.