# Is every finite subgroup of $C^*=$ set of all non-zero complex numbers cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is every finite subgroup  of $C^*=$ set of all non-zero complex numbers cyclic?

I see that the set $A_n=\{z:z^n=1\}$ is a subgroup of $C^{*}$.

Any element of $A_n$ is a solution of $z^n=1$.Now the solutions of $z^n=1$ for any $n\in \Bbb N$ are $e^{\frac{{2ki\pi}}{{n}}};1\le k\le n$ and hence the subgroup $A_n$ is generated by $a=e^{\frac{{2ki\pi}}{{n}}}$ and hence cyclic.

But is it the case that any finite subgroup of $C^{*}$ is of the form $A_n$ for some $n$?

I am having problems to answer this question.If it is true then it answers the original question.

Please help.

Comment: You should put emphasis on "But is it the case that any finite subgroup of $C^*$ is of the form $A_n$ for some $n$?" if this is what you really want to know. Otherwise, this is [a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic).

Comment: It would be a good thing if the group of all nonzero algebraic numbers were cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is such finite subgroup, for every $g\in G, |g|=1$. Since if $|g|\neq 1$, $1,...,g^n,..., n\in N$ is infinite. You can write $g=e^{ic}$. Let $N$ be the order of $G$, $g^N=1$. This implies that $e^{Nic}=1$ and $c=p{2\pi\over N}$ for some integer $p$. We deduce that is a subgroup of the group generated by $e^{2i\pi\over N}$, and $G$ is cyclic since it is a subgroup of a finite cyclic group.

Comment: This answer contains a mistake I think. How can you be sure that $H \leq \langle e^{2i\pi/N} \rangle$?

Comment: You can fix the proof by writing $m:= lcm\{o(h) \mid h \in G\}$ and then $H \leq \langle e^{2\pi i/m}\rangle$

Comment: Also, the step $|g| = 1$ is necessary. You can immediately deduce this by $g^{ord(g)} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

All *finite* subgroups are cyclic. In fact this statement is true for $F^*$ for any field $F$. However one can easily construct infinite subgroups that are not cyclic.  Consider all elements of finite order. This is a proper subgroup: it is precisely all the roots of unity. Because there are infinitely many prime numbers, one can see that not all numbers of the form $e^{2\pi i/p},\ p$ a prime, can be obtained as a power of a single complex number.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question;Its edited

Comment: For a proof see Serre's "A Course in Arithmetic", the first few pages.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb C^\times$ is a subgroup of itself, and is certainly not cyclic.

If you're talking about *proper* subgroups only, consider the **unit circle**, or the group of nonzero complex numbers whose real and imaginary parts are both rational. Or $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question;Its edited