# Finite group with property that for $d \mid |H|, x^d = 1$ has at most $d$ solutions is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

> Let $H$ be a finite group of order $n$ with the property that for every $d\mid n, x^d = 1$ has at most $d$ solutions. Then $H$ is cyclic.

Let $\alpha = \{h'_1, h'_2, ..., h'_k\}$ be the set of all orders of elements. If $n \in \alpha$ done. Assume $n \notin \alpha.$ Consider $\mathrm{lcm}(h'_1, ..., h'_k) = h'.$ We know that there exists an element $g$ such that $o(g) = h'.$ Since $n \notin \alpha, h' \neq n.$ Hence, we have that for all $x \in H, x^{h'} = 1.$ However, we have $n$ solutions where $h' < n.$ Contradiction. It must be that $n \in \alpha.$

Does this work?

Comment: How do you know there is an element of order $h'$?

Comment: For another approach look at the responses to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic)

Comment: Here is a hint: for every such $d$, count the number of elements with this order.

Comment: Oh for every such $d$ the number of elements is either 0 or $\phi(d).$ And since we know that $\sum_{d | n} \phi(d) = n,$ none of those values can be 0 otherwise contradicting that the group is of order $n.$ Hence, we have that the number of elements of order $n$ is nonzero so cyclic.