# About the Center of the Special Linear Group $SL(n,F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

I want to classify the center of the Special Linear Group.
I already determined the center for $SL(n,F)$:

$$Z(SL(n,F))=\left\{ \lambda I_n:\lambda^n=1 \right\}.$$

I showed that $Z(SL(n,F))$ is itself a group and now

> I want to show that $Z(SL(n,F))$ is cyclic and has a order dividing $n$.

I thought this is possible by regarding the map $SL(n,F)\rightarrow P(F)$, $P(F)$ being the projective space. The kernel of this map is $Z(SL(n,F))$. How do I have to argue now?

Comment: This is basically the $n$-th roots of unity in $F$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have already proved that $Z\bigl(SL(n,F)\bigr)$ is (isomorphic to) the group $\{\lambda\in F\mid\lambda^n=1\}$. And this group is cyclic, since [finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903). Extending $F$ to its algebraic closure $\overline F$, you'll get a group with $n$ elements (the $n$ roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$). Since your group is a subgroup of this one and this one has order $n$, the order of your group divides $n$, by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: I dont quit understand how we get the isomorphism?

Comment: @johnka The isomorphism is provide by the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\{\lambda\in F\,|\,\lambda^n=1\}&\longrightarrow&Z\bigl(SL(n,F)\bigr)\\\lambda&\mapsto&\lambda\operatorname{Id}_n.\end{array}$$

Comment: If $char\ F=p>0$, we can't say the $n$ roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$ in $\overline F$ has $n$ (distinct) elements. Rather, write $n=p^rm, (p, m)=1$, then there are exactly $m$ elements.