# Typo in Algebra by Artin regarding center of the special linear group $SL_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, general-linear-group

I saw this question that was asked a year ago: [Centre of the special linear group $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ or $SL(2,\mathbb R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901069/centre-of-the-special-linear-group-sl-2-mathbb-r-or-sl2-mathbb-r)

I will link the photo in question here:

[image]

Shouldn't the last line read, "$SL_n(\mathbb R)$ consists of $I, -I$ if n is even, and is trivial if n is odd"?

Comment: So the is not a typo in Algebra by Artin (see title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is written is correct. The center of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ consists of $I,-I$. The author does not talk about $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ for $n \geq 3$.

But you are right, for $n$ odd $-I$ has determinant $-1$ and thus does not live in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, thus definitely also not in its center.

Comment: The author does talk about what happens for $n>3$ in the last line.

Comment: Am I right about $n$ being even, too, since $-1^{2m}=1$?

Comment: The author says that the center of $S_n$ is trivial for $n \geq 3$. $S_n$ is another group than $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$