# What is the size of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(K)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to figure out what the size of the projective special linear group $$\operatorname{PSL}_n(K) := \operatorname{SL}_n(K)/Z(\operatorname{SL}_n(K))$$ is, when the field $K$ has $q$ elements and in case $n=2$.

I was able to figure out the size of the special linear group $$|\operatorname{SL}_n(K)| = q^{\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)}\prod_{i=2}^n(q^i - 1)$$ which is correct acording to the solution. So I tried to get the size of the center, and the solution states $$|Z(\operatorname{SL}_2(K))| =\begin{cases}1,\quad \text{ if $q$ is even} \\ 2, \quad\text{ if $q$ is odd}\end{cases} $$

**Question:**
The first case seems clear so far, but I'm having a hard time to understand the second case. What is the second element in the center?

Comment: If $q$ is even, you only have $I_2$ in the center (because $+1=-1$ if $q$ is even), but if $q$ is odd, you have $I_2$ and $-I_2$.

Comment: Thanks, but how is that connected to the odd/even attribute?

Comment: If $q$ is even, then you are in a field of characteristic $2$, so $1=-1$, so $I_2=-I_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of $\text{SL}(2, K)$ is isomorphic to $\{\lambda \in K : \lambda^2 = 1\}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587986/about-the-center-of-the-special-linear-group-sln-f) question). This follows more generally from the fact that the center of $\text{GL}(2, K)$ consists of diagonal matrices (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299626/the-center-of-operatornamegln-k)).

The solutions to $\lambda^2 = 1$ in $K$ are $1$ and $-1$, yet when the characteristic of $K$ is $2$ these elements are the same. When $K$ is even there is therefore only one element in the center---the identity $I$. But when $K$ is odd the characteristic is greater than 2, so $I$ and $-I$ are two distinct elements of the center.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\& -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! But how is that connected to the even/uneven thing?

Comment: If $q$ is even, then $-1$ is the same thing as $1$ and this is just the identity element.