# $n$-th roots of unity in general field

Tags: field-theory

It is well known that if $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field, then the group
$$
G=\{x\in \mathbb{F}:x^n=1\}
$$
is cylic. Is it true also when $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the group of $n$-th roots of unity is cyclic for all fields. We can use the following result:

**Theorem:** Any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of *any* field is cyclic.

There are several references for this on MSE. Fabio gave one above.

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich Burde. I don't see the reference. What do you mean by MSE?

Comment: Math Stack Exchange.  If you search for your question, you may find that it has been asked and answered already, as in this case. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic

Comment: @boaz Sorry, MSE is a shorthand for this site here.