# $G \in F^*$ be a finite subgroup. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $F^*$ be its multiplicative group and $G \in F^*$ be a finite subgroup. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Here is my attempt, I am not sure if it's correct.

*Proof*. Let $n=|G|$, we know that $1 \in G$ and $x^n=1$ for every $x \in G$. But clearly $x^{n-1} \ne 1$ for some $x \in G$, otherwise we would have $n$ distinct roots to $x^{n-1}=1$. Hence there is an $x \in G$ with order equal to $n$. $\square$

Is there an easier answer to this? And is my solution correct? Thanks.

Comment: If $x^{n-1}\neq 1$ for some $x$, then why should this $x$ have order $n$? Take $x=-1$ and $n=100$.

Comment: Have a look at the proofs at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic). Then it is clear, that the proof needs more than $3$ lines.

Comment: You can also read the first two-three pages in Serre's delicious book "A course in Arithmetic" .

Comment: thank you everyone!