# Prove that $G$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and denote by $a(n,G)$ the number of
>   elements $g\in G$ such that $g^n=1$. Prove that if $a(n,G)\le n$ for
>   each divisor of $|G|$, then $G$ is cyclic.

I don't know how to prove this statement. I try to use the fact that $|G|=\sum_{n |\ |G|}\varphi(n)$ (where $n$ divide $|G|$) but I do not know how to proceed with the demonstration. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: What is $\varphi(n)$?

Comment: @BillWallis : Euler's totient function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903)