# Easy proof of the existence of a primitive element in a finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Is there an "easy" proof of the existence of a primitive element in a finite field? My book uses three lemmas and a theorem to get there, and I can't shake the feeling that there's an easier way of doing it.

I've made some attempts using proof by smallest counter-example, looking at the set of all finite fields with a certain number of elements. E.g. it's trivially true for the set of all finite fields with 2 elements, and then moving from e.g. $A_k$ to $A_{k+1}$ (where $A_k$ is the set of all finite fields with $k$ elements) you pick a field $F\in A_{k+1}$ which does not have a primitive element, and look at a subfield of it where you exclude one element. This subfield then *does* have this property. After that I got stuck.

Anyone know of any relatively "clean" proofs?

Comment: Are you sure by removing one element of a field you get a subfield?

Comment: See Andrea's answer at [Finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic). In particular, the whole multiplicative group of non-zero elements is cyclic, so there is a primitive element.

Comment: Depends. If you have covered the structure theorem of finitely generated (in particular finite) abelian groups, then it becomes a bit easier.