# A reference for the following result : Faithful irreducible representation over a field of characteristic zero implies cyclic centre.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

I was reading this [page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_primitive_implies_cyclic-center) about the following result :

If a group has a faithful irreducible representation over any field of characteristic zero, then the center of the group is cyclic.

The said page has proof, but I am looking for a published book/paper, if available, for referring to.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically cycles back to the fact that a *finite* subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field of characteristic zero is cyclic. See I.M. Isaacs, [Character Theory of Finite Groups](https://books.google.nl/books?id=MeE7BFXwQroC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Lemma (2.27). And also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic).

Let me explain it in more detail. First, if $\mathfrak{X}$ is a representation affording the character $\chi$, then $ker(\mathfrak{X})=ker(\chi)$. Here $ker(\mathfrak{X})=\{x \in G: \mathfrak{X}(x)=I\}$ and $ker(\chi)=\{x \in G: \chi(x)=\chi(1)\}$, see also Lemma (2.19) of Isaacs' book.

Now if $\chi$ is faithful then $ker(\chi)=\{1\}$. Hence Lemma (2.27) (d) and (f) will give you that $Z(G)$ must be cyclic.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain a little more how to use Lemma 2.27 in this case? Sorry.

Comment: Edited into the answer. Hope you understand it now.