# Find the smallest positive integer generate $F_p^* $

Tags: group-theory

I am learning about groups generators and there are questions regarding finding the smallest positive integer that generates $F_p^* $. I am currently trying to calculate based on each element of the set, but I wonder if there is a more systematic way to do this kind of question? For example, $F_{17}^*$ would be big enough for me to feel calculating each element by hands not efficient anymore!

Comment: Another wording of this question is "what is the smallest primitive root modulo $p$?", which might help you search for what is known. There's no formula, and indeed I don't think we can do that much better than try each integer in turn (although there are fast ways to "try" integers).

Comment: What is $F^*_p$?

Comment: In the note, I see they define $F_p^* $ as the set of number from 1 to $p-1$ that are relatively prime to $p$. Do you know if there is any formula for  determine the number of generators $F_p^* $ have if $p$ is prime?

Comment: The multiplicative group of the finite field $\mathbb F_p^\times$ is [cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic) of order $p-1$, so the number of [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_(finite_field)) is the Euler totient function $\phi(p-1)$