# Are there non cyclic subgroup of the set of nonzero rationals under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Non cyclic subgroup of nonzero rationals under multiplication:

My motivation to question is curiosity. Moreover,this would be another proof that the set of non zero rationals under multiplication is not cyclic group.

I see that set of dyadic rationals is subgroup of rationals under addition, so, I tried to show non zero dyadic rationals is non cyclic subgroup of non zero rationals under multiplication, but turned out, it's not even subgroup.

The set of dyadic rationals is $\{\frac{a}{2^{n}}:a,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: Huhn, I just learned that my life-long belief that "cyclic" does not include $\mathbb Z$ is wrong.

Comment: [**finite** subgroups of multiplicative groups of fields are always cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The positive rationals form a subgroup, which is actually the free abelian group on a countable basis (because of unique factorization): any positive rational number can be written in a unique way as
$$
\prod_{k\ge0} p_k^{e_k}
$$
where $p_0=2,p_1=3,p_2=5,\dotsc$ is the sequence of distinct primes and the exponents $e_k$ are integers, all zero except for a finite number of them (so the product is actually finite).

You're not required to mention this, but it should give an idea: take the subgroup $H$ generated by $2$ and $3$. The elements of $H$ can be written in a unique way as $2^a3^b$ where $a,b$ are integers. Is this subgroup cyclic?

Answer (score 6):

Consider $G=(\Bbb{Q}\setminus \{0\} , \cdot)  $ and $\textrm{sgn}:G\to C_2=\{\pm 1\}$ defined by $$\textrm{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$$

Claim:

1. $\textrm{sgn}$ is an onto homomorphism.
2. $\ker(\textrm{sgn}) =\Bbb{Q}^{+}$
3. $H=(\Bbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$ is not cyclic ( even not finitely generated).

Answer (score 4):

Note that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of non-zero rationals (or for that matter, non-zero elements of any field) is cyclic.

Thus, your subgroup needs to be infinite.

How about taking the subgroup generated by $\{1/p : p\text{ is an odd prime }\}$ ?

This is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ as it doesn't contain $1/2$. Can it be cyclic?

Comment: How is this a subgroup? In particular, how is it closed under inverses? What is the inverse of $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Subgroup **generated** by...

Comment: The solution mentions taking the subgroup \textbf{generated by} the set $\{1/p : p\text{ is an odd prime }\}$